# Handling push notification when app is killed - React native/nodejs [Android]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, push-notification, expo

Any suggestion to push notification for : foreground, background & killed app. I tried with expo but it seems like it doesn't support push notification when the app is killed so I'll appreciate any suggestion

backend tech :  Node js
frontend tech : react native expo

Comment: Try it, https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/overview

Comment: @Dmitro_ is that working for closed app or just foregound & background ?

Comment: Yep, read how it works - https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/events#background-events